# ASP.NET Webmethod in aspx.cs page not able to access Page.Request object

Tags: asp.net, httprequest, webmethod

Does anyone know how to access HttpRequest.Cookies within a static method with [WebMethod] attribute from an aspx.cs page?

It won't let me do it because method is static .

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool PostToTwitter(string identityUrl, string message, bool autoFollow)
{
  Page.Request.Cookies -- object reference is required for non-static field
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use,

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies
```